# Adding .m source code files for room for long or extra routines

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, xcode4

My Xcode .m source files are getting long due to numerous routines, some of which are rather long. I'm looking for the way to add additional .m files and then call the routines in them from my main .m file. I understand the mechanics of adding source files, I really want to know how to call routines in source files other than the one I am currently in.

Example:

mySource.h contains

```
-(void) myRoutine01;

-(void) myRoutine02; ...

-(void) myRoutine99;
```

Inside mySource.m I call a routine thusly:

```
[self myRoutine01];

[self myRoutine02];

[self myRoutine03];
```

I'd like to keep mySource.m manageable in length such that I am doing mostly logic stuff with calls to routines that are actually housed in other source files. Some routines can get very long and housing them in their own .m files would be most convenient.

How do I call routines in another source file? Do I just replace "self" with something?

Comment: Do you want the "routines" to just be split into multiple '.m' files, but as members of the same class, or are you asking how to add new classes so that your current class can reference them?  You could actually solve your problem either way, although the latter is usually the better choice.

Comment: The external routines are members of the same class. I'm creating to many data analysis routines to fit comfortably inside a single .m file.

Answer (score 2):

What you are calling "routines" are actually methods.

You can organize your methods using Objective-C categories, placed in multiple files.
A category is a way to add methods to existing Objective-C classes. Read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocCategories.html) to learn more about this.

This way, you can organize your source files and keep them small, by grouping specific methods into a specific category.

For instance:

MyClass.h

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject
{}

- ( void )someMethod;

@end
```

MyClass+Misc.h (category)

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@interface MyClass( Misc )

- ( void )someOtherMethod;

@end
```

MyClass.m

```
#import "MyClass.h"
#import "MyClass+Misc.h"

@implementation MyClass

- ( void )someMethod
{}

@end
```

MyClass+Misc.m

```
#import "MyClass+Misc.h"

@implementation MyClass( Misc )

- ( void )someOtherMethod
{}

@end
```

Comment: My old school C background is showing! So it's just a matter of adding another header file for the external methods?

Comment: ; ) No problem... You'll need to add a header file per category, as well as an implementation file for each one.

Comment: I'm studying Catagories now. I'm not smart enough to ask better questions just now. Must read and experiment.

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask again if you need more help.

Comment: Okay, I'm seeing issues. My first issue is referencing buttons and labels in my original view, which is part of the point of needing extra routines. This extra category needs to interface with the original view. How do I address the view assets?

Comment: Not sure to understand... If you are speaking about your class instance variables, they are available on categories as well.

Comment: Example of a line of code that is generating an error:

[myButton01 setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Xcode doesn't like myButton01.   :-(

Comment: Where is myButton01 declared?

Comment: myButton01 is in the original header. I've added the #import but no go.

Comment: I wish to table this for now. I have too much to learn. Thank you.

Comment: The error is that the compiler is not recognizing my labels and buttons. I get a stop sign in the editor. The problem is my utter lack of experience with this concept, I'm doing something very wrong at a very fundamental level. I have to study the code posted above and the samples in the Apple documentation. The "+" is confusing me as is where to put my category names. With the reading I've done so far categories is the answer to my wish to extend a class over multiple .m files. The mechanics are eluding me at the moment. I'll get it soon enough.

Comment: What must I change in the original .h and .m files? Where do I declare my category?

Comment: After much experimentation it appears that screen items (NIB items) are not directly accessible or declarable in the category. I find that buttons  and labels need to be setup in the main.m file while category.m can support the actual logic. I can't set myLabel.text in the category but I can do string manipulation and then, via extern variables, set myLabel.text back in the button handler. Is this right?

In Main.m I set up buttons and things:
-(IBAction) BooButtonClicked:(id) sender {
    [self SetBooString];
    [self SetBooLabel];
}

SetBooString can be in Category.m but SetBooLabel can't.

Comment: Thanks, man! I was stuck with this for an hour because I didn't realise that its needed to include both class and category headers in .mm file of class implementation not in header!